# Как вывести знак квадратного корня?

Tags: python-3.x

Необходимо вывести знак корня - √ на экран монитора, в результат программы. Как это сделать?

Comment: Вывод непосредственно знака

Comment: Очень смешно...

Comment: На экран монитора, в результат программы

Comment: Яснее, да пока еще не совсем. Как вы сейчас выводите текст, и что вам мешает сделать вывод этого знака как и других букв - он не выводится, или вместо него "?" или еще что-то? Кусочек своей программы покажите, где вы текст выводите. Используйте кнопку правка подвопросом.

Comment: А экран монитора - это что именно? Окно графического интерфейса? Консоль? Если консоль, то какой операционной системы и с какой кодировкой?

Comment: Давайте с другой стороны: у вас какие-то проблемы с выводом? Простой `print('√')` по какой-то причине не работает?

Answer (score 3):

Вот так можно вывести любой Unicode символ, если знать его код.
Например значек корня:

```
print(u'\u221a')
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать вариант, который предложил Kromster (он будет даже лучше, наверное).
А можно просто создать строку, в которую записать знак квадратного корня(если вам нужно будет проводить взаимодействия со знаком).
Вариант записи может быть таким:

```
s = '√'
```

или через юникод(что, конечно же, является одним и тем же, но первый вариант выглядит красивее)

```
s = u'\u221a'
```

Если в последствии вам нужно будет писать математические выражения типа "√25", то я бы обыграл это следующим способом:

```
print(s, end="")
print(15 + 10)
```

Или так:

```
a = 15 + 10;
print(s,a)
```

Comment: Спасибо, я пытался написать сразу в IDLE аль-кодом. Но как оказалось можно было в блокноте и потом копнуть в программу)